# How to make `fit_generator` work with `tf.keras.Model`

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am implementing a `tf.keras.Model` (not a `Sequential` model!) that should be trained using `fit_generator`. 
However, `fit_generator` raises an error, probably because input shapes are not available at compile time.

Here is a minimal example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


class MyModel(tf.keras.Model):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()
        self.dense1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation=tf.nn.relu)
        self.dense2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation=tf.nn.softmax)

    def call(self, inputs, training=None, mask=None):
        return self.dense2(self.dense1(inputs))


class MyGenerator(tf.keras.utils.Sequence):

    def __len__(self):
        # Number of batches per epoch
        return 1

    def __getitem__(self, _):
        # Generate one batch of data
        x = np.array([[1., 2., 3.]])
        y = np.array([[0., 1., 0.5]])

        return x, y


if __name__ == '__main__':
    m = MyModel()    
    g = MyGenerator()

    m.compile(tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(), loss=tf.keras.losses.mean_squared_error)
    m.fit_generator(g)
```

The last line raises

```
AttributeError: 'MyModel' object has no attribute 'total_loss'
```

So what is the proper way to use `fit_generator` in a custom Keras model?

Comment: add `tf.enable_eager_execution()` line, before creating the model. This will fix the error.

Comment: @Mitiku Works indeed, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In Tensorflow 2.x, eager execution enabled by default. `Model.fit_generator` is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. So you have to use `Model.fit`, which supports generators.

Please refer `TF 2.4` compatible code as shown below

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
import numpy as np


class MyModel(tf.keras.Model):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()
        self.dense1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation=tf.nn.relu)
        self.dense2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation=tf.nn.softmax)

    def call(self, inputs, training=None, mask=None):
        return self.dense2(self.dense1(inputs))


class MyGenerator(tf.keras.utils.Sequence):

    def __len__(self):
        # Number of batches per epoch
        return 1

    def __getitem__(self, _):
        # Generate one batch of data
        x = np.array([[1., 2., 3.]])
        y = np.array([[0., 1., 0.5]])

        return x, y


if __name__ == '__main__':
    m = MyModel()    
    g = MyGenerator()

    m.compile(tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(), loss=tf.keras.losses.mean_squared_error)
    m.fit(g)
```

Output:

```
2.4.0
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 224ms/step - loss: 0.4725
```